# Open New text file, and save as

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following;

```
Sub Export_Coupon_Data()

Dim rng As Range
Dim Sourceworksheet As Worksheet
Dim DestFile As String
Dim cel As Range


Application.DefaultFilePath = "C:\Users\Documents"

DestFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\A.txt"

Open DestFile For Output As #1


    Set rng = Worksheets(1).UsedRange           ' get an area with data on the sheet
    Set rng = rng.Columns(rng.Columns.Count)    ' get the last column inside rng
    
 
    If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then                 ' rng can contains 1 or many cells
        Dim arr As Variant                      ' in case of many cells
        arr = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
        Print #1, Join(arr, vbCrLf)             ' write many values to file
    Else                                        ' in case of 1 cell
        Print #1, rng.Value                     ' write single value to file
    End If
    
    Close #1

End Sub
```

What this does is read a table of data, take the final column and print it to a text file I have named A.

However, the context of this problem is that one column will house data for materials testing, whereby the inputs will be things such as Weight, material name etc etc, therefore new columns will be added every day, and updated as a database of results.

What I need is for the programme to read the final column on excel, i.e. a new material, and then export that data to a .txt file, BUT each material needs to have its own text file, therefore I need to;

Open a new text file,

Read the final column

Write to new text file

Save new text file,

From my basic understanding and asking, I think I may need a Loop? but I am too inexperienced to write code to that effect.

In addition, it would be useful If I could save the files as a an input of one of the cells I.e. Material ID - 345-xyz, and then the text file that is saved is 345-xyz.

Any help would be great

Comment: Why do you think you need a loop? As far as I can see all you need to do is change the filename.

Answer (score 0):

As commented above, the only thing that seems to be missing is a way to pick/generate the filename.  Below is an example of how it could be done if a user is allowed intervene in the process and enter the name.

If you want to automate the filename creation, replace `GetOutputFileName`'s content with logic that reads the MaterialID cell that you mention above.  Return the filename generated using the cell's value.

```
    Option Explicit

    Sub Export_Coupon_Data()

        Dim rng As Range
        Dim Sourceworksheet As Worksheet
        Dim DestFile As String
        Dim cel As Range
        
        
        Application.DefaultFilePath = "C:\Users\Documents"
                    
        Dim outputTextFilename As String
        outputTextFilename = GetOutputFileName()
        
        If Len(outputTextFilename) = 0 Then
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        DestFile = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\" & outputTextFilename
        
        Dim fileExists As String
        fileExists = Dir(DestFile)
        If Len(fileExists) > 0 Then
            MsgBox "File: " & DestFile & " already exists"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        
        Open DestFile For Output As #1


        Set rng = Worksheets(1).UsedRange           ' get an area with data on the sheet
        Set rng = rng.Columns(rng.Columns.Count)    ' get the last column inside rng
        
     
        If rng.Cells.Count > 1 Then                 ' rng can contains 1 or many cells
            Dim arr As Variant                      ' in case of many cells
            arr = Application.Transpose(rng.Value)
            Print #1, Join(arr, vbCrLf)             ' write many values to file
        Else                                        ' in case of 1 cell
            Print #1, rng.Value                     ' write single value to file
        End If
        
        Close #1

    End Sub

    Private Function GetOutputFileName() As String            
        GetOutputFileName = vbNullString
        
        Dim result As String
        result = InputBox("Enter Filename")
            
        If Len(result) = 0 Then
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        result = result & ".txt"
        
        GetOutputFileName = result
    End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate it